# Angular JS directives as native inputs

Tags: angularjs

How can I do this thing:

HTML:

```
{{bar}}
<input type="text" ng-model="bar">
<foo ng-model="bar">
```

JS:

```
app.directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<textarea>{{value}}</textarea>',
        scope: { value : '=' }
        controller: function($scope, $element){

        }
    }
});
```

I want change "bar" value when foo directive changes and change value in foo directive when text input changes.

How can I do that?

text input changes: textarea changes.
textarea changes: text input changes too.
but textarea should be as directive with restrict: "E"

Comment: Do you want the 'value' in your directive be the same as bar?

Comment: yes, it's should be one value in all places.
really, I want replace my old text inputs based on JQuery with new directives without pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem is that your isolate scope expect an attribute called `value`.

`value: "="` means that you expect an attribute with tha name of value.

`value: "=ngModel"` means that you will have a property called value in your isolated scope linked to the ng-model attribute.

I give you here 2 examples:

http://jsbin.com/EyareCo/1/edit

The first one, just bind your `bar` with the internal scope via a `value` attribute. Works just fine.

The second one, uses `ngModelController` which is more advanced that the first one. The idea behind using `ngModelController` is to provide validation and more stuff.

Comment: text input changes: textarea changes. textarea changes: text input changes too. but textarea should be as directive with strict: "E"

how can I do that?

Comment: @KoIIIeY what do you mean with strict? There is nothing like `strict` in directives. Do you mean `restrict: 'E'`? (which is already there).

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use scope.bar in all three cases

It would look like

`{{bar}} 
<input type="text" ng-model="bar">
 <foo value="bar">`

You shouldn't use ng-model in your directive, because you deal with the isolated scope hear, which contains only 'value' field. 
The '=' binding that you've provided will do the rest of the job for you. When value changes through the ng-model from your input it will also change inside your directive

**UPDATE:**
To bind textarea with 'bar' value you should also use ng-model hear, but instead of 'bar' we should use 'value' hear, because as I write before, there is no scope.bar field here, but only scope.value field, but it directly binded with 'bar' property of parent scope from outside. So template will looks like : `<textarea ng-model='value'></textarea>`.

If you want to update value when some event happens (not-angular event), you should use $scope.$apply to notify that values have been changed.

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TNySn/1/
Hear, when we click button, all 3 values changing because changeValue function wrapped in $scope.$apply function, and when we change textarea text, text-box and {{bar}} output are also change

Comment: Can I deal with some value in directive and then put it's value to ng-model of parent scope?

Comment: @KoIIIeY please, look at updated answer, I've also provided jsfiddle link

Comment: Uh, why mix classic javascript with angular? There is no need to set an onclick event like that...

Comment: @JesusRodriguez I'm use button.onclick only to show how to do it and why we need to use $apply, the question here is not related to button

Comment: And why you need to use $apply?

Comment: no, unfortunately, it's wrong example. Textarea, that creates by angularjs should change value of "bar" too.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez Because in this case, angular don't know nothing about onclick event, and if we remove $apply, values will not update. For example when we use $http and $timeout insted of $.get and setTimeout, we don't need $apply, because it will be done for us internally

Comment: Ya, I know, but there is no need to use onclick. You can use ng-click in your directive.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez I'm understand about what you talking too. But as I said, this is only example of event that is not controlled by angular. You can provide yours if you think that such usage is confusing

Comment: @KoIIIeY But now bar already changing when the value change. Otherwise, textbox and {{bar}} will state the same, but they change. Can you clarify what exactly do you want?

Comment: text input changes: textarea changes. textarea changes: text input changes too. but textarea should be as directive with strict: "E"